# Yosemite and photos

Tags: macos, video, photos

I upgraded my mac to Yosemite and now I can't find my photos or video folder. My iCloud just has the 'loading' spinning circle so I'm not sure if they've gone there? Just can't find them anywhere!

Comment: Which application do you use to access your photos on your Mac? Do you still have the Pictures and Movies folders?

Comment: And if you open Finder - preferences - sidebar! are they there and checked ?

Answer (score 1):

With the plain screen, click on "Go."  Under it, you should see the "Home" folder.  If you click on it, you should find all your folders.  I have tagged them a certain color so I can easily find them.

Hope this helps!  [image]